# How to do a request with Instasharp

Tags: c#, instagram, instasharp

I have to do some requests with instasharp but I don't know how to do it, I tried something after searching on the site but it makes Visual Studio freeze.

Here is my code, in this one I just want to make a simple request (getting location by their latitude and longitude) in order to learn how does it work.

So I created a config with my client and my secret, and I used it to create a Location `Endpoint`. But after doing `result1.Wait()`, it freezes.

```
var clientID = "Myclient";
var clientSecret = "Mysecret";

InstaSharp.InstagramConfig config = new InstaSharp.InstagramConfig(clientID, clientSecret);

var location = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Locations(config);

var result1 = location.Search(45.759723, 4.842223);

result1.Wait();

foreach (InstaSharp.Models.Location l in result1.Result.Data)
{
    MessageBox.Show(l.Name);
}
```

Have you any solutions or tips I could use? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's freezing because you are not using the `await` keyword in conjunction with the `async` keyword. Also, it's `result1.Data` not `result1.Result.Data` (when you are looping through the returned list of locations.)

Try this.

```
var clientID = "Myclient";
var clientSecret = "Mysecret";

InstaSharp.InstagramConfig config = new InstaSharp.InstagramConfig(clientID, clientSecret);

var location = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Locations(config);
var result1 = await location.Search(45.759723, 4.842223);
foreach (InstaSharp.Models.Location l in result1.Data)
{
    MessageBox.Show(l.Name);
}
```

I got the default `20` locations for the `lat, long` you have in your code, and the name of the place(s) were `Lyon` in most of them.